# How can I automate reporting spam on Google groups?

Tags: spam-prevention, google-groups, automation

I'm a member of a particular Google group such as: [math](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sci.math). I want to automate the process of clicking on a messsage, either from a certain user or having a subject line such as "books", and then reporting it as spam through a series of left and right mouse clicks and choosing the appropriate option.

For example, to report a Google message as spam, I have to first select the message, left click the RHS for "report abuse", select the "spam" button, then left click "submit report".